# Apache logging and range requests

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

If an Apache server receives a single HTTP request with multiple ranges requested in the header, in the access log, does it log one entry per range requested, or just one entry like normal?

The reason I ask is because we've been seeing a large number of log entries from certain user agents, which is similar to the issue described here - [Apache - disable range requests - disadvantages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/304859/apache-disable-range-requests-disadvantages)

What I'm not sure about, is whether the user-agent is genuinely sending 000s of requests like the logs indicate - in which case we need some sort of network flood control in front of apache - or whether the large number of logs is misleading and actually there is only one real HTTP request, in which case the solution in the link above is sufficient.

I can't find any info on this specifically in the Apache docs or by googling.

Answer (score 0):

A single request, even with multiple (potentially overlapping) ranges, should only log one entry.

Check `tcpdump` and watch the traffic to be sure, but it sounds like you are getting large numbers of distinct requests.

Comment: Could you source this? My experience has been the opposite, especially with iPhone's "resumable download" feature.